# Warning when trying to save a large matrix

Tags: matlab

I need to save a matrix, `shape_collector_square`, which has size 256*256*18496. I get this warning:

> Warning: Variable 'shape_collector_square' cannot be saved to a
>   MAT-file whose version is older than 7.3. To save this variable, use
>   the -v7.3 switch. Skipping...

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not planning on opening the saved `mat` file in matlab with version < 7.3, simply use the `-v7.3` switch as suggested by the warning. If you do plan opening the saved mat file on an earlier matlab version, than consider splitting the matrix up into smaller pieces and save them separately. Than, when you load them, just reassemble the original matrix.